# install jest with npm in javascript

Tags: javascript, npm

i try to install **[jest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHCF0.png)** by local or global with npm but it does not install

my **npm** version is 7.5.2
and my **node** version is 12.22.5
also i have **ubuntu**

and i try this commands :

```
npm i -D jest
npm i -g jest
npm i jest
```

but jest dont installed

this is the error :
alireza@SUCCESS:~/Desktop/test$ sudo npm i -D jest
[sudo] password for alireza:
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@jest%2ftransform reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-14T12_19_47_677Z-debug.log

[image: it is the error]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error is related to an invalid cache so my first suggestions is to run:

`npm cache clean --force`.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: no i try it but the error still exist

Comment: i install jest by yarn successfuly